# How to keep a clean browser history in a backbone.js app?

Tags: backbone.js, browser-history

My backbone.js has three views:

1. List of categories
2. List of items in category
3. Form for individual item

I'm using backbone.js router to navigate between these views. The user flows in the app go 1<-->2, 2<-->3 and 3 --> 1. The user can navigate back and forth using browser back and forward buttons, which is wanted behavior. Deep linking to any item works also.

The problem is that I want to keep the history clean. Here's an example usage flow:

- User opens list of categories. History: "Category list" (correct)
- User select "My category". History: "My category" < "Category list" (correct)
- User select "My item". History: "My item" < "My category" < "Category list" (correct)
- User fills form and saves, is redirected to "Category list". History: "Category list" < "My item" < "My category" < "Category list" ( should be just "Category list" )

Another example:

- User opens url of "My category"
- User presses home button. History: "Category list" < "My category", should be "Category list"

Any ideas on how to implement this in a clean way?

Comment: I think you should [open your search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+clear+browser+history+using+javascript), it is not about Backbone but javascript, browsers standars and security issues. You will find several tricks.

Comment: I realize that the handling of history is a browser feature and not directly related to backbone. The question is how to manipulate the history within the context of an app that uses backbone routing.

Comment: Just to clarify what I'm looking for with this question and bounty:
- A way to use history.back(), history.forward() and history.replaceState (or in this case router.navigate(fragment, {replace:true}) to achieve the use cases above
- It is enough to solve this use case, doesn't have to be a global solution
- I know we're in a bit of hacky territory, but an elegant or at least self-contained solution is apprecieated

Comment: A bit after the fact, but I decided to rewrite my solution as an open source component, in case it's useful for someone else. It can be found at https://github.com/omahlama/historyhelper

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to implement the first example that you provided. You cannot implement the first example because there is no way to "delete" the browser history using Javascript.

> There is no way to clear the session history or to disable the back/forward navigation from unprivileged code. The closest available solution is the location.replace() method, which replaces the current item of the session history with the provided URL.
>
> - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history

At best you can prevent the current page from being added to the browser history by using `window.location.replace` or `window.history.replaceState`.  Backbone.js provides a convenient way of doing this by calling `router.navigate(fragment, [options])` on your router object and specifying `{replace: true}` in the options.

Instead of relying on different routes to determine which view to display, I would try instead writing a master view which could handle showing/hiding the specific views.

### EDIT

Ok, entering hacky territory...

Since it seems that the "Category List" page is the page where history should be "reset", the solution I have posted attempts to solve both use cases you have mentioned. The code keeps track of a `historyState` variable, which represents when the "category-list" page is visitied as well as the other pages visited after it.

```
// in your application init...
$(function(){
    window.historyState = -1;
    router = new Backbone.Router({ 
        routes: {
            "category-list": category-list,
            "category": category,
            "item": item
        }
        
        category-list: function(){
            historyState = 0;
        },
        
        category: function(){
            if(historyState >= 0)
                historyState++;
        },
        
        item: function(){
            if(historyState >= 0)
                historyState++;
        }
    });
});
```

- If `historyState` is `-1` - we have not yet visited the "category-list" page.
- If `historyState` is `0` - we are currently on the "category-list" page.
- If `historyState` is greater `0` - number of pages visited since viewed "category-list" page.

Now anytime a link is used to navigate to the "category-list" page, make sure it calls the following method to handle the appropriate navigation.

```
function routeToCategoryList(){
  if( historyState > 0 ){ 
    // 'category-list' already exists in our history route to that page.
    window.history.go((historyState * -1));
  } else {  
    // otherwise, don't store an entry for the current page we are on.
    router.navigate("/category-list", {trigger: true, replace: true});  
  } 
}
```

If the 'category-list' page has already been visited go back in history the appropriate number of entries (this unfortunately keeps the other pages in the history, so you can still go forward to them).  Otherwise if the 'category-list' page hasn't been visited yet navigate to it and be sure not to add the current page to the history.

Comment: I think that for solving the example User Cases the question exposes you don't need to _delete_ the browser history but to _rewind_ to an initial state, and I think this is allowed.

Comment: Still I think the behavior intended to achieve is against the browsers' standard and it is not gonna be a friendly road.

Comment: About being against browsers standards: you are technically right, but this is a web app, targeted to mobile phones. The user expectations are that of an app, not a web page - the physical back button of WP7 and Android phone really adds ease of use to the user interface. Pressing back to go up the tree feels very natural, going down to the leaf you were in with back feels wrong and broken.

Comment: @OlliM I'm pretty sure you're your reasons to play against browser standards, I just wanted to say than this uses to need the double of effort.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to delete history from backbone history, you can re-route the navigation by adding some logic by getting current fragment

or you can use history.js (Works on most of the browser)

**while https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history is only for Mozila firefox** so this does not work for android app