# Backbone history

Tags: backbone.js, history, router

Is there a way to remove a particular fragment from the backbone history? Here is a use case:

I have a login view, and once the user successfully logs in, there is no need for that view to remain in the history because it is meaningless to go back to the login page after successful login. However, I still need the login view in the history if the user navigates to the login page first, does not login but navigates away from the login page to another page (say password reset page). If the user accidentally clicked on the password reset link and navigated there, clicking on the back button should bring the user back to the login page.

Any chance of doing this with backbone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906648/how-to-keep-a-clean-browser-history-in-a-backbone-js-app

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question: Yes, there is a way to handle this, you just have to implement it in the required routers you have set up in your app.

For example, if you want to:

1. Start history on first page after login
2. Start history on password reset page (or any other gated page)

Do the following (this code snippet should be placed in your routers, in the initialize function):

```
initialize: function(options) {
  this.route("pageId", "login", function(number){
      //Call to Backbone.history.start() wether or not you want the history to start on this page
      //E.g. don't call it on the index route, just in /reset-password and so on.
});
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: on sign-in action use this to redirect:

```
Backbone.history.navigate('/destination/page', {replace: true, trigger: true});
```