# Clear the Backbone.history

Tags: javascript, android, ios, backbone.js, cordova

I am developing phonegap application using backbone Js. To enable the back button functionality i am using `Backbone.history.start();`.

For one scenario, I want to clear all the application history and invalidating the back button feature.

It would be great if anyone will answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the Backbone source code I see it's possible to disable Backbone.history with `Backbone.history.stop();` so this may give you the expected behaviour.

```
// Disable Backbone.history, perhaps temporarily. Not useful in a real app,
// but possibly useful for unit testing Routers.
stop: function() {
  Backbone.$(window).off('popstate', this.checkUrl).off('hashchange', this.checkUrl);
  clearInterval(this._checkUrlInterval);
  History.started = false;
},
```

Comment: You're welcome @nagendra. Now you should accept the answer if the issue is solved. Cheers.

Comment: Actually I am developing the Android Web application using Phonegap and backbone. 

If I clear or disable the Backbone.history using your function, My app stopped working with the other functionalities. :(:(

Comment: Do you know how to limit Backbone.history stack to certain numbers? 
Ex: My history stack size should be always 15.

Comment: I don't know exactly what do you want to achieve, but maybe this questions can clear a bit your mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606634/backbone-router-getting-history-length-for-back-button and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906648/how-to-keep-a-clean-browser-history-in-a-backbone-js-app